# @Transactional not working in Spring Boot with a custom Transaction Manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-transactions

I'm trying to write my own custom PlatformTransactionManager for working with Neo4J (Note - I don't want to use OGM for various reasons, which means not using Spring Data).

I've written a very simple Neo4jTransactionManager and added it to my context, as well as the @EnableTransactionManagement annotation, and then added @Transactonal to my healthcheck - and it's not triggering anything.

Code as follows: (Note - Neo4jOperations is a wrapper around Driver to make calling the database easier, similar in intention to JdbcOperations)

```
class Neo4jTransactionManager(private val driver: Driver) : AbstractPlatformTransactionManager() {
    companion object {
        private val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Neo4jTransactionManager::class.java)
    }

    class Neo4jTransaction(private val driver: Driver) {
        var session: Session? = null
        var transaction: Transaction? = null

        fun start() {
            if (session != null) {
                throw CannotCreateTransactionException("Transaction already started")
            }

            session = driver.session()
            transaction = session?.beginTransaction()
        }
    }

    override fun doCommit(status: DefaultTransactionStatus) {
        val transaction = unwrapTransaction(status)
        LOG.debug("Committing transaction: {}", transaction)

        if (transaction.transaction == null) {
            throw NoTransactionException("No current transaction")
        }
        transaction.transaction?.success()
        transaction.transaction?.close()
        transaction.session?.close()
    }

    override fun doBegin(transaction: Any, definition: TransactionDefinition) {
        (transaction as Neo4jTransaction).start()
    }

    override fun doGetTransaction(): Any {
        return Neo4jTransaction(driver)
    }

    override fun doRollback(status: DefaultTransactionStatus) {
        val transaction = unwrapTransaction(status)
        LOG.debug("Rolling back transaction: {}", transaction)

        if (transaction.transaction == null) {
            throw NoTransactionException("No current transaction")
        }
        transaction.transaction?.failure()
        transaction.transaction?.close()
        transaction.session?.close()
    }

    private fun unwrapTransaction(status: DefaultTransactionStatus) : Neo4jTransaction {
        return status.transaction as Neo4jTransaction
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true, mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
class DatabaseConfig {
.....
    @Bean("transactionManager")
    fun neo4jTransactionManager(driver: Driver) = Neo4jTransactionManager(driver)

    @Bean
    fun neo4jHealthcheck(neo4jOperations: Neo4jOperations) = Neo4jHealthcheck(neo4jOperations)

}

@Transactional
class Neo4jHealthcheck(private val neo4jOperations: Neo4jOperations) : AbstractHealthIndicator() {
    companion object {
        private const val QUERY = "MATCH (n) RETURN count(*) as count"
    }

    @Transactional
    override fun doHealthCheck(builder: Health.Builder) {
        val count = neo4jOperations.queryOne(QUERY).get("count").asInt()

        builder.up()
                .withDetail("Nodes", count)
                .build()
    }
}
```

I'd expect to see my healthcheck emit some log messages around the transaction stuff, and to see them in the stacktrace when debugging. But I don't see any of that, so it's almost as if it's completely ignoring my @Transactional annotations.

What have I missed?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see Neo4jHealthcheck is not a spring component. So there is maybe no proxy created.

You must add @Component or any of the subtypes to Neo4jHealthcheck

Have a look at an example with acutator and transactions:

https://github.com/simasch/actuator-transactional

Comment: So I'm not using Component Scanning, preferring to wire everything up by hand so I can see what's going on. However, I've added @Component to the healthcheck just in case - and it's made no difference :(

Comment: Can you try to remove  
    fun neo4jHealthcheck(neo4jOperations: Neo4jOperations) = Neo4jHealthcheck(neo4jOperations) and annotate Neo4JHealthcheck and the Neo4jOperations with @Component. I made a simple test and for me it works

Comment: So - Interesting fact. My Transaction Manager works fine. I just can't make the healthcheck transactional for some reason. If I put @Transactional on my Neo4jOperations methods then they *are* transactional exactly as I expected. Which then begs the question of why one class works and not the other :(

Comment: I assume that the healthcheck is not called trough a proxy as the Neo4jOperation. But it's just guessing.

Comment: I'm just not sure why. They're both being created in exactly the same way. Ah well, it works now at least :)